# What is the difference between iterdescendants() and iterchildren() in lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

In LXML python library, how to iterate? and what is the difference between iterdescendants() and iterchildren() in lxml python ?

Answer (score 4):

Using `iterchildren` you iterate over direct children (for the tree below it means you iterate over only 7,5), while using `iterdescendants` you iterate over direct or indirect children (in the case of the tree below you will iterate over 7,5,2,6...etc.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can iterate over tags using the following iterations:

`iterancestors(self, tag=None, *tags) :`

- Iterate over the ancestors of this element (from parent to parent).

`iterchildren(self, tag=None, reversed=False, *tags) :`

- Iterate over the children of this element.

`iterdescendants(self, tag=None, *tags) :`

- Iterate over the descendants of this element in document order.

`iterfind(self, path, namespaces=None) :`

- Iterates over all matching subelements, by tag name or path.

`itersiblings(self, tag=None, preceding=False, *tags) :`

- Iterate over the following or preceding siblings of this element.

**The difference can be understood by the following code:**

```py
from lxml import etree
xml_str = '<main><child><c1><c11/><c12/></c1><c2/></child><child1/><child2/></main>'
parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True)
root = etree.XML(xml_str,parser)
```

**`Iterdescendats()` will return all the children and all the tags within the child tags as well:**

```py
    for i in root[0].iterdescendants():
        print(i.tag) 

    output:
    c1
    c11
    c12
    c2
```

**`Iterchildren()` will return only the child tags:**

```py
    for i in root[0].iterchildren():
        print(i.tag)

    output:
    c1
    c2
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use iterchildren() you iterate over first level childs. When you use iterdescendants() you iterate over childs and childs of childs.